# Iterating through list to remove items won't process all the records

Tags: python-2.7, loops

I am using Python 2.7

I have two CSV files with similar lists, but with a few differences. I can compare the two files to get a list of strings of the records from the input list that do not match the correct list. But when iterating over the list of unmatched strings, I run into an issue...

I keep a simple count of the records that I process through in my for loop. When I get to the else statement, I remove spaces and when I remove the unmatched item from the list, I run into my issue. My noMatchList has 30 records. When that remove happens, I only get a count of 20 iterations instead of a full 30. With that remove commented out, I get a full 30 iterations.

Any idea what's going on here? Thanks for your time.

My relevant code:

```
for unMatched in noMatchList:
    # Check if an uppercased version of the unMatched item is in GISlist. If so, remove the unMatched item
    count +=1
    upperCased = unMatched.upper()
    if upperCased in GISlist:
        noMatchList.remove(unMatched)
    else:
        # Check if the uppercased version of the unmatched item with no spaces around hyphen is in GISlist
        # If it is in the GISlist, remove it. 
        if ' - ' in upperCased:
            noSpaces = upperCased[0:upperCased.index('-')-1] + '-' + upperCased[upperCased.index('-')+2:]
            if noSpaces in GISlist:
                noMatchList.remove(unMatched)
```

Comment: Except pass is an [antipattern that you should avoid](https://realpython.com/blog/python/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: I used the try-except to try and account for when the unmatched record i'm iterating over does not have a ' - ' in it. But I have changed my code above to take that out.

Answer (score 1):

Found what I was looking for in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

When starting my for loop, i put a slice onto the noMatchList and it worked like a charm! Example:

```
for unMatched in noMatchList[:]:
```

Comment: But do you know *why* it worked? This is a fairly fundamental Python thing, and it would pay you to understand it.

Comment: I believe so. By adding the slice, it takes all of the items in the list when i start the loop. Rather than without the slice, where it looks at all the items in a list that is constantly changing.